# Update a column from all tables where column name and value equals to given value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a value in all tables where column name and the column value equals to given data

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT table_schema, table_name  AS table_name_str 
   FROM information_schema.columns 
   WHERE column_name = 'customerID' AND table_schema='testdb' 
) AS tb1
WHERE table_name_str.customerID=5
```

When I try to run this it gives the following error message:

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'table_name_str.customerID' in 'where
>   clause'

Comment: you are selecting * from tb1, you named it like that. table_name_str it's a label name you use for a value, not a table to select a column for

Comment: You cannot use the `table_name` returned by the subquery to access the actual table in the database. You need some form of dynamic sql to do this.

Comment: what are you trying to do with meta data table? and again comparing the values of it??

Comment: @avisheks i'm trying to update tables record in a particular DB column name called **customerID**  update the value ( from 5 to 10 )

Comment: why are you querying information_schema then?

Comment: That is the only thing i got to select all table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT table_schema, table_name  AS table_name_str ,customerID
   FROM information_schema.columns 
   WHERE column_name = 'customerID' AND table_schema='testdb' 
) AS tb1
WHERE tb1.customerID=5
```

Try above code.

You have to specify that column in inner query then only you can put where condition on it in outer query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If fail to see why this answer got an upvote. The inner query just returns the string literal values of schema and table names. You cannot use these values to access the real tables in the database.

Comment: where is `customerID` coming from in information_schema table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i got know about **The inner query just returns the string literal values of schema and table names**  so cannot use these values to access the real tables in the database.
I just show what i'm trying to do logically

Comment: @NSK What you need is called [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in MySQL.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i didn't check inner query's table name.I am just thinking it's normal table and he did not put that `customerID ` column in inner query.So that's why it's give error and i had put that column in inner query and made according changes in outer where condition..\

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a two step process:


 1. Create the `UPDATE` query string:

```
SELECT concat('UPDATE ', table_schema,'.', table_name,' SET customerID=<new_value> WHERE customerID=5;' as qry_str
FROM(
  SELECT table_schema, table_name  
  FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
  WHERE 
    column_name = 'customerID' 
    AND table_schema='testdb'
) AS tb1
```

2. Run the `UPDATE` statements:

```
UPDATE testdb.table1 SET customerID=6 where customerID=5;
UPDATE testdb.table5 SET customerID=6 where customerID=5;
...
...
and so on.
```

Let me know if this works.